# Shannon Fano generating bits

Tags: c#, compression

I want to compress an image file with Shannon Fano. The image coded with 256 different letters. So it means my table will be sized with 256. But I couldn't get that bits will be 8 bits length again and the file will be bigger than old one.
(2 ^ 8 = 256)

So whats point of using Shannon Fano? What I missed? My shannon fano code :

```
 static void shannon(int l, int h)
    {
        int size = h - l + 1;
        if (size > 1)
        {
            int mid = size / 2 + l;
            for (int i = l; i < h + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i < mid)
                    s[i].bits += '0';
                else
                    s[i].bits += '1';
            }
            shannon(l, mid - 1);
            shannon(mid, h);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I use only frequencies to generate bits

Comment: A bit late I happen to come across this - `I use only frequencies to generate bits`. You don't seem to be using the symbol frequencies at all, which is probably the key to why it doesn't work for you.